# "git config -l" shows my username/email set but git push asks for username

Tags: git, github

Given my email and username are included in  ~/.gitconfig:

```
$cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = MyFirst MyLast
    email = myemail@gmail.com
```

And `git config -l` "sees" them:

```
$git config -l
user.name=MyFirst MyLast
user.email=myemail@gmail.com
```

Why is `git push` *not* seeing them?

```
 $git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Here is a bit more info:

Status:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

Remotes:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<owner>/<repo> (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<owner>/<repo> (push)
```

Comment: Git doesn't assume that your name in `~/.gitconfig` is the same as your github username. The git software is a separate thing from the github website. I recommend adding SSH keys to your github account so that you don't have to enter your username/password every time you push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Those are two very different data parts that aren't related***

The username in your configuration is for things like setting the author of commits.

When you are prompted for a user name when pushing to a remote, that is something different.  Those are authentication credentials.

Git does not assume that the configured user name is the same as the authenticating credential user name.

This is a good thing.  For instance, a very real example:

My **configured user name in Git**: `Thomas Stringer`

My **GitHub user name**: `tstringer`

If that was assumed, that would be quite annoying for me to have to override or reconfigure.

Comment: Yes i keep forgetting to use ssh (in conjunction with ~/.ssh/config).  `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/<owner>/<repo>`

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a commentary/addition to the answer (which will be accepted) by @Thomas Stringer:

The way to handle this is to us ssh (in conjunction with ~/.ssh/config).

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/<owner>/<repo>
```